# how to run the same step again without datasource in soapui

Tags: java, soap

I don't have soap ui pro. I am testing the web service. The actual implementation is i need pass one error code on the request, and the corresponding error description should be displayed on the response. I need to add this assertion. Every time the description in the response varies.

Here is the thing i want exactly...

Every time i need to run the same request but the error code (which is input) only should be changed on each time and the description varies on the response. How to validate this? Is there any way to do this without data source.

Regards,
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way i have created.. is there any way to improve the code to do better way;

```
import java.io.File;
File file = new File('c:/customers.csv');
InputStream inputFile =  new FileInputStream(file);
String[] lines = inputFile.text.split('\n');
List<String[]> rows = lines.collect {it.split(',')}
log.info('There are ' + rows.size() + ' customers to be inserted');
for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
  String[] row = rows.get(i);
  String errorcode = row[0];
// log.info(errorcode)
 String errorDescription = row[1];
 //log.info(errorDescription)
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('errorcode', errorcode);
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('errorDescription', errorDescription);
testRunner.runTestStepByName("createCard-1");
log.info(errorcode +"Finsihed")
}
```